# add_meta_box() input field displaying at the top of the page

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

thanks for taking the time to read this. I've had a look through any similar questions and haven't found a case like this. It's probably something really silly. This is my first time using `add_meta_box()`.

Basically, I'm trying to add a meta box to a custom post type. The field itself is showing, but its right at the top of the page (where errors usually appear)

See screenshot:

[image: meta_box displaying at the top of page]

Here is the code I'm using for adding the box and the callback. This is inside of class.

```
public function room_settings_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box(
        'room-settings',
        __( 'Room Settings', 'book-it' ),
        'room_settings_meta_box_callback',
        'rooms'
    );
}

public function room_settings_meta_box_callback( $post ) {

    wp_nonce_field( 'room_settings_nonce', 'room_settings_nonce' );

    $value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'room-settings', true );

    echo '<input style="width:100%" id="room-settings" value = "' . esc_attr( $value ) . '" name="room-settings">';
}
```

I'm also a bit stuck with the `get_post_meta($key)`. Would that be the meta-box ID?

Other examples that I saw all seem to start with an `underscore (_META_KEY)`

I'll make sure to edit this if I find the solution myself.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=add_meta_box%28%29&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need to set the 5th context parameter of the wordpress [add_meta_box()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/) and state that you want your meta box to appear in the 'normal' context.

```
public function room_settings_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box(
        'room-settings',
        __( 'Room Settings', 'book-it' ),
        'room_settings_meta_box_callback',
        'rooms',
        'normal',
        'high'
    );
}
```

See my [RaceCPT.php](https://github.com/emeraldjava/bhaa_wordpress_plugin/blob/master/src/core/cpt/RaceCPT.php) as an example